# Change Gizmos.DrawWireCube Cube Limits, based in childs transform.position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**How can change width of `Gizmos.DrawWireCube`, based in child transforms (`Gizmos.DrawWireSphere`) `transform.position` or maybe the left/right limit of the transform?**

My code so far:

position.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Position : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnDrawGizmos () {
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, 0.75f);
    }


}
```

FormationController.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FormationController : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject enemyPrefab;
    public float width = 10;
    public float height = 5;
    public float speed = 5;
    public float padding = 1.5f;
    public float SpawnDelaySeconds = 1;
    private int direction = 1;
    private float boundaryLeftEdge,boundaryRightEdge;
    private PlayerController playerController;
    // Use this for initialization

    void Start () {
        float distance = transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z;
        Vector3 leftmost = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, distance));
        Vector3 rightmost = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 0, distance));
        boundaryLeftEdge = leftmost.x + padding;
        boundaryRightEdge = rightmost.x - padding;
        SpawnUntilFull();
    }



    void OnDrawGizmos () {
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position, new Vector3 (width, height));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        float formationRightEdge = transform.position.x + 0.5f * width;
        float formationLeftEdge = transform.position.x - 0.5f * width;
        if (formationRightEdge > boundaryRightEdge) {
            direction = -1;
        }
        if (formationLeftEdge < boundaryLeftEdge) {
            direction = 1;
        }
        transform.position += new Vector3(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        if (AllEnemiesAreDead()) {
            SpawnUntilFull();
        }
    }

    void SpawnUntilFull () {
        Transform freePos = NextFreePosition();
        GameObject enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, freePos.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        enemy.transform.parent = freePos;
        if (FreePositionExists()) {
            Invoke ("SpawnUntilFull", SpawnDelaySeconds);
        }

    }

    bool FreePositionExists () {
        foreach( Transform position in transform) {
            if (position.childCount <= 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    Transform NextFreePosition() {
        foreach (Transform position in transform) {
            if (position.childCount <= 0) {
                return position;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    bool AllEnemiesAreDead () {
        foreach(Transform position in transform) {
            if (position.childCount > 0) {
            return false;
            }           
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**An example:**

I'm making a game like "space invaders", but i can't figured out how when the most left invader die, the invaders formation changes to smaller formation... so the new most left invader "touches" the left boundary.

**My scene:**

[image: my scene]

Ignore the gizmo (the circle) at the most top

Comment: when the left invader dies: do you want to make the box smaller, so that it starts at the next left invader or do you want to move the next left invader more left?

Comment: @JinJi maybe... the first one. What i want is that they move right and left and always touches the edges of the camera (disregarding the padding)... when the most invader dies: the new most left invader most go all to left, or better saying the whole formation

Comment: When the player kills the most left/right invader (enemy) the rectangle gizmo becomes smaller in width

Comment: your first comment says that the enemies must move and the box must not change. your second comment says that the box must change.

Comment: @JinJi sorry i don't spell very good english... the box must change in order the formation touch the left and right edges

Comment: @JinJi the rectangle (formation) (the box) need to adjust itself to the existing enemies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FormationController : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject enemyPrefab;
    public float widthToLeft = 5;
    public float widthToRight = 5;
    public float height = 5;
    public float speed = 5;
    public float padding = 1.5f;
    public float SpawnDelaySeconds = 1;
    private int direction = 1;
    private float boundaryLeftEdge,boundaryRightEdge;
    private PlayerController playerController;
    // Use this for initialization

    void Start () {
        float distance = transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z;
        Vector3 leftmost = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, distance));
        Vector3 rightmost = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 0, distance));
        boundaryLeftEdge = leftmost.x + padding;
        boundaryRightEdge = rightmost.x - padding;
        SpawnUntilFull();
    }



    void OnDrawGizmos () {
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position, new Vector3 (widthToLeft+widthToRight, height));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        float formationRightEdge = transform.position.x + 0.5f * widthToRight;
        float formationLeftEdge = transform.position.x - 0.5f * widthToLeft;
        if (formationRightEdge > boundaryRightEdge) {
            direction = -1;
        }
        if (formationLeftEdge < boundaryLeftEdge) {
            direction = 1;
        }
        transform.position += new Vector3(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        if (AllEnemiesAreDead()) {
            SpawnUntilFull();
        }
    }

    void SpawnUntilFull () {
        Transform freePos = NextFreePosition();
        GameObject enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, freePos.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        enemy.transform.parent = freePos;
        if (FreePositionExists()) {
            Invoke ("SpawnUntilFull", SpawnDelaySeconds);
        }

    }

    bool FreePositionExists () {
        foreach( Transform position in transform) {
            if (position.childCount <= 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    Transform NextFreePosition() {
        foreach (Transform position in transform) {
            if (position.childCount <= 0) {
                return position;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    bool AllEnemiesAreDead () {
        foreach(Transform position in transform) {
            if (position.childCount > 0) {
            return false;
            }           
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

i just changed width to widthToLeft and widthToRight

when the invader dies:

```
public void OnInvaderDeath() {
    float mostLeft = 10000;
    float mostRight = -10000;
    foreach( Transform invaderTransform in invaderList ) {
        if( invaderTransform.position.x < mostLeft )
            mostLeft = invaderTransform.position.x;
        if( invaderTransform.position.x > mostRight )
            mostRight = invaderTransform.position.x;
    }
    widthToLeft = mostLeft + 0.75f;
    widthToRight = mostRight + 0.75f;
}
```

Comment: i tried, and with some modifications because OnInvaderDeath is on another script... but didn't work. i will try adapt this and i will post notices soon.. thanks